# String Comparison when list of strings start with "/"

Tags: c#, asp.net, string-comparison

Trying to return true or false for this code:

```
var searchString = "abc";
var list= new List<string>() { "/abc", "/xyz" };
bool found= list.Any(x => searchString.Contains(x, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

`found` returns false in this case, however I need it to find "abc" and return true from the defined list `{"/abc", "/xyz"}`. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You should change the comparison:

```
var searchString = "abc";
var list= new List<string>() { "/abc", "/xyz" };

bool found = list.Any(x => x.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
//                         ^          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Because "abc" does not contain "/abc", but vice versa. You want the searchString to be searched in every item of the collection.